# nomogram for competing risk regression

Tags: r, rms

I would like to drawing nomogram for competing risk analysis. and I Use the ordinary linear regression trick to predict the linear predictor from the competing risk regression, however, I don't know how to get the linear predictor from the crr() function. I have the following code.

```
  library(cmprsk)
 library(rms)
set.seed(10)
ftime <- rexp(200)
fstatus <- sample(0:2,200,replace=TRUE)
cov <- matrix(runif(600),nrow=200)
dimnames(cov)[[2]] <- c('x1','x2','x3')
z <- crr(ftime,fstatus,cov)
z.p <- predict(z,cov)
n=60#suppose I want to predict the probability of event at time 60(an order)
df<-data.frame(y=z.p[n,-1],cov)
ddist <- datadist(df)  
options(datadist='ddist') 
lmod<-ols(y~rcs(x1)+rcs(x2)+rcs(x3),data=df)#y is not linear predictor of crr fitting, this ols modeling can be wrong. the R^2 will not be 1. 
nom<-nomogram(lmod)
plot(nom,lplabel=paste("prob. of incidence T",round(z.p[n,1],2),sep="="))
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "y is not linear". You are modeling it with regression splines so the predictors are piecewise cubic functions of three different variables.

Comment: I mean y is not a linear predictor from crr fitting, I think rcs applied to covariates is not correct

Comment: Can we get the naming conventions settled? I see no "y"-object in your code (except in the formula and that doesn't count).

Comment: y is the name of a variable in df data frame

Comment: df<-data.frame(y=log(log(z.p[n,-1])),cov)

Comment: Which produces all NA's for `y`. Perhaps you should start a clean session and run again?

Comment: Do you want to delete this question?

Comment: @42- no, I updated it and this code works